# The dual of the primal problem

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the primal linear programming problem 
Maximize z =c(transpose) x
Subject to Ax<=b 
X is unrestricted .Then its dual problem given by 
Minimize ź=b(transpose) w
Subject to A(transpose) w =c 
W>=0

I can't complete the proof 
proof:
 Because of x is unrestricted let x =u-v ,  u,v>=0
**The primal problem will be** :
Max. Z=c(transpose)(u-v)
Subject to A(u-v)<=b
u,v>=0

**The dual problem:**
Min. Z=[b(transpose)-b(transpose)] [ u   v]
Subject to  [A(transpose)-A(transpose)] [u   v]>=c
u,v>=0

How I can continue to get A(transpose)w=c   w>=0 
Thanks in advance
If I suppose that w=u-v that does not mean that w>=0

Answer (score 2):

Setting $x=u-v, \ u,v\geq 0$ in the primal you get the symmetric dual 
\begin{align}
\min \ & b^{\top} w\\
& A^{\top} w \geq c\\
& -A^{\top}w \geq -c\\
&  w\geq 0
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
\min \ & b^{\top} w\\
& A^{\top} w = c\\
&  w\geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: You mean -A(transpose)w>=-c. Thanks 

Comment: No, it is  $-A^{\top}w \leq -c\ \longrightarrow A^{\top}w \geq c$

Comment: oh yah I understand it's just simple step ....thank you very much

Comment: you were right. I considered the primal in your question as a minimum problem. I'm sorry about that!